# How to avoid wasting time waiting for VS on-line help to load?

Tags: visual-studio

I've never received any useful information from Visual Studio on-line help.  I keep accidentally opening on-line help but pushing [F1] when I mean to push [Esc].  It takes about 8 seconds to load and it won't let me close it.  Is there an easy way out of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `F1` as the keyboard shortcut for help.

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard. Search for `Help.F1Help`, and remove the shortcut.

("Never received any useful information"?  There's the whole of the MSDN library potentially in there.  Though I'm with you on the annoying delay.)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the [F1] key from the keyboard!  You can still push the switch underneath the missing key with a pencil if you need to.

I did this last year and have not had a single occasion to press [F1].

:-)

Comment: I know it sounds funny, but it's dead serious.  Some people (gamers in particular) remove the "Start Menu" key from the keyboard to avoid pressing that by accident as well.

Comment: Well, I guess that's why SO doesn't let you post and then immediately answer your own question.  But then again, this does get the job done well. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Install it locally?